# Problem in reading numbers

Tags: c#, numbers

Hello friends i am a total beginner in c#.
I want to read numbers in the following format

2

1 10

3 5

For reading 2 i have used `Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())` method and successfully stored it. But for the next input i want to read the number and after a space i want to read another number. I cannot use ReadLine() method.. I have used `Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read())`

But the number 1 is read as 49

So How do i achieve reading numbers

In java i have found a similar class called Scanner which contains methods line `nextInt()`
Is there any C# equivalent to that class.

In short i just want to know how to read and store numbers(integers or floats) in C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ReadLine()` and just split on whitespace, i.e.,

```
void Main( string[] args )
{
    var numbers = new List<int>();
    while(whatever)
    {
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        var lines = input.Split( 
            new char[] { ' ' }, 
            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries 
            );

        foreach( var line in lines )
        {
            int result;
            if( !int.TryParse( line, out result ) )
            {
                // error handling
                continue;
            }

            numbers.Add( result );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sit, I want to store the numbers read in the second line in two different variables

Comment: @varunit: They are stored as separate variables held within a list.  You can store them however you like, this is just an example to give you the general idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Split method, to break the line into numbers.

```
while (true)
{
   var s = Console.ReadLine();
   if (s == null) break;
   foreach (var token in s.Split(' '))
   {
        int myNumber = int.Parse(token);
        // ...  do something ....
   }
}
```

Comment: This is fine but what i need is to store the next two numbers read in two different variables.. What can i do now?

Comment: What do you want to do with the number?  The int value is now in the `myNumber` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You problem is about converting strings into integers, as Console.Readline always returns a string.

There are many ways to parse multiple ints, but you will basically need to split the string using some method. I don't know of a `Scanner` in C# (but I guess you should seach for some kind of *tokenizer* to find it, since this would be the standard name.

Writing one is not that hard, especially if you only expect integers to be separated by spaces. Implementing it in a method could be something like

```
   // Optional seperators 
   public IEnumerable<int> ParseInts(string integers, params char[] separators)
   {
       foreach (var intString in integers.Split(separators))
       {
            yield return int.Parse(intString);
       }
   }


   public IEnumerable<int> ParseInts(string integers)
   {
        return ParseInts(integers, ' ');
   }
```

Comment: *"as Console.Readline always returns an int."* - I imagine that's a typo as `Console.ReadLine()` returns a string, not an int.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("Path to your file");
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            if (line.Trim() == "")
            {
                continue;
            }
            string[] numbers = line.Trim().Split(' ');
            foreach (var item in numbers)
            {
                int number;
                if (int.TryParse(item, out number))
                {
                    // you have your number here;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing this on HackerRank a lot, here's a helper method I use for reading an array of integers:

```
static int [] StringToIntArray(string s) {
    string [] parts = s.Split(' ');
    int [] arr = new int[parts.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) {
        arr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(parts[i]);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Here's a sample reading two numbers on one line, then two lines with those many numbers into arrays:

```
string [] parts = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
int n = Convert.ToInt32(parts[0]);
int m = Convert.ToInt32(parts[1]);
int [] a = StringToIntArray(Console.ReadLine());
int [] b = StringToIntArray(Console.ReadLine());
```

Sample input:

```
3 5
40 50 60
10 20 30 100 7500
```